# google analytics weekly report specific time

Tags: google-analytics

google analytics weekly report specific time

We have the weekly  Customization report and the report Email are received random time on setup time.
It is possible to setup the specific time?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in Google Analytics.

Comment: Is it possible in Daily report ? Could you help up any reasons? Where can we educate for the issue, Tomek Lechowicz?

Comment: GA does not give you such possibilities. Question is what exactly you need it for? Do you need some xlsx/pdf report to be send on exact time to some VIP? Or maybe you just need to send some report for other system to process? I ask because GA has rather complex API, which gives you possibility to extract all the data you need and process them on your side. You are able to take extract the data on exact date/time, prepare the report and send/use it however you want. To do it, you need some basic programing skills. Question, what is your final goal?

Comment: Our final goal is consistency.  We plan to review 8 AM on Monday because we  received the time in previous week.  We can view at noon in this report.  We could work in programming but need the documentation. We appreciate and admire your knowledge Tomek Lechowicz!

Comment: I suppose you could use Google Analytlics Spreadsheet Add-on in this case ( [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) ). This will, in simple steps, enable you to define any report you want, same way as you defined reports in GA. It also gives you possibility to schedule generation of this report, with hourly precision. Try it out and check if it meet your requirements.

Comment: Hi @TomekLechowicz. Do you got any idea how can I define a weekly report inside the addon? I'm trying to implement that and cannot find any documentation... Thank you man.